# Trouble extracting password protected zip

Tags: macos, zip

I used a shell command on Mac OS 10.9.5 to create a password protected zip file similar to:

zip --password 1234 data.zip data.txt

I am sending the file to someone else and they are able to open the password protected zip file.

When I use letters and numbers for the password (such as www111, I can extract the file without a problem.

When I include characters such as $ and % as the password (for example, $www111%), I cannot extract the file myself, but the person receiving the file can extract the file with the password.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: What shell is this? $ and % are probably reserved characters which will need escaping in the command line.

Comment: I was issuing a terminal command using Xojo. The encrypted zip file is created without a problem and when sent to the person on the other end, they open it without a problem. It is only when I try to open it, the password doesn't work.